# xpath1.0: post-filtering a node set by change in attribute when preceding sibling is not possible

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Below, I have a subset of *car* nodes. I then want to process this further by filtering-in by a change in an attribute.

Because preceding-sibling works on the document, the second xpath below will not work if the preceding-sibling node is a *non-yellow car*. Is there a simple way to achieve this in xpath or with minimal xslt?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="yellowCars" select="/cars/car[@color = 'yellow']"/>
    <changedinspectiondate>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$yellowCars[not(@inspectiondate = preceding-sibling::car[1]/@inspectiondate)]"/>
    </changedinspectiondate>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Apparently you want to process distinct inspection dates of yellow cars only. If so, I would suggest you do this by [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info).

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I'll do that, but out of curiosity, if it wasn't a grouping issue, could it be done in xpath1.0? e.g. using position()?

Comment: Only if you *copied* the nodes into the variable. But then you would also have to convert the resulting RTF into a node-set. Alternatively, you could process the nodes using a recursive named template.